# Extract special characters using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

How to parse the special characters from a html with DomDocument?

For eg, if I want  to fetch a paragraph from [**this**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aditya) wikipedia page, I'm able to get that with-

```
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aditya");
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$items=$dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach($items as $item){
    echo $item->textContent;
    break;
}
```

but in the response I get-

> **Ã„Â€dityas**  instead of **Ādityas**,
>
> **Ã Â¤Â†Ã Â¤Â¦Ã Â¤Â¿Ã Â¤Â¤Ã Â¥ÂÃ Â¤Â¯** instead of  **आदित्य** and so on..

Basically I just want to know how to properly encode these characters when fetched with DOMElement. Later I'll be saving them in a database or as plain text only.

Comment: you need to tell your browser what character set all that is. YOUR browser has absolutely NO clue that you fetched this text from wikipedia or whatever, so it'll get rendered in the brower's default charset, which is obviously not the same charset as the data you fetched. This has NOTHING to do with DOM at all.

Comment: @MarcB Cool. But how can I tell `DOMDocument` which charset I want to use? I tried adding this meta: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in the `<head>` of the html before loading into the DOMDocument; but still getting the same result.

Comment: like I said, this has NOTHING to do with DOM. Dom is pulling out some bytes it finds in the specified part of the html document, and then you're echoing it out. You're not echoing out the entire document, just a small snippet of it, so you need to have **YOUR** code tell the receiving end (the browser) what charset to use, e.g. `header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8")`